# Require password at shut down in AppleScript: How do run scripts before shutdown?

Tags: applescript, shutdown

People have an annoying habit of shutting down my computer when I'm not looking, so I want to require a password to shut down my computer. However, I don't know how to make a script run at shutdown. How do I do this? (Help with the password-getting is appreciated, but I think I can handle it.)

EDIT: An idea is that it will run when the computer turns on, and then keep listening for shutdown until it's requested, and intercept it. I can do the first part, but what about the rest?

Comment: Maybe you can alter the logout script here: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2006081701162739

Comment: Hmm. I guess I could learn bash. Thanks for the suggestion and link!

Comment: You can run an AppleScript from bash with the osascript command.